# On Ejabberd, how a user can leave a conference?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

On `mod_muc` configurations I can see that there’s an option `max_user_conferences` and that its default is **100**. In my case, I want a specific user to moderate all sessions in the app, so this account will have to connect to maybe 500 conferences for example. I can set the `max_user_conferences` to 1000, but is it possible to make this number go down by leaving a conference or clearing it for this user somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can think three ways to accomplish that:

A) Tell that user to leave the rooms that need no administative tasks, so that the account doesn't reach the limit of 500 conferences.

B) Increase the limit to higher than what that account needs. But of course, other accounts can also join so many rooms. Maybe that is not a problem in your server, if you are an enterprise without spammers or bad guys.

C) Apply this small patch to ejabberd source code:

```
diff --git a/src/mod_muc_room.erl b/src/mod_muc_room.erl
index 9e633a604..e3d7c93e1 100644
--- a/src/mod_muc_room.erl
+++ b/src/mod_muc_room.erl
@@ -2049,11 +2049,11 @@ add_new_user(From, Nick, Packet, StateData) ->
    mod_muc_opt:max_user_conferences(StateData#state.server_host),
     Collision = nick_collision(From, Nick, StateData),
     IsSubscribeRequest = not is_record(Packet, presence),
-    case {(ServiceAffiliation == owner orelse
-        ((Affiliation == admin orelse Affiliation == owner)
+    case {ServiceAffiliation == owner orelse
+        ((((Affiliation == admin orelse Affiliation == owner)
           andalso NUsers < MaxAdminUsers)
           orelse NUsers < MaxUsers)
-       andalso NConferences < MaxConferences,
+       andalso NConferences < MaxConferences),
      Collision,
      mod_muc:can_use_nick(StateData#state.server_host,
                   StateData#state.host, From, Nick),
```

And grant that account (let's say tomrules@example.com) admin rights in the MUC service:

```
acl:
  muc_admin:
    user:
      - tomrules@example.com

modules:
  mod_muc:
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
      - allow: muc_admin
```

Now, that user can join infinite rooms, the other accounts are limited as usual.